# Accessing Azure webhook data with python

Tags: python-3.x, azure, webhooks, azure-automation, azure-webhooks

How do you access using the Python programming language the `WebhookData` object in the Azure automation webhooks. I read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) regarding this, but it is in PowerShell, and not helping in my instance. My Azure webhook URL endpoint is successfully receiving data from a custom external application. I would like to read the received data and run logic driven by the received data. As shown on the below screenshot, I am receiving the data in Azure.

[image: WEBHOOKDATA coming into the Azure]

This is the error message I am getting when I attempt to access the `WEBHOOKDATA` input parameter:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Temp\rh0xijl1.ayb\3b9ba51c-73e7-44ba-af36-3c910e659c71", line 7, in <module> received_data = WEBHOOKDATA NameError: name 'WEBHOOKDATA' is not defined
```

This is the code producing the error message:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

# Here is where my question is. How do I get this in Python?
# Surely, I should be able to access this easily. But how. 
# Powershell does have a concept of param in the documentation - but I want to do this in Python.
received_data = WEBHOOKDATA   
#convert JSON to string
received_as_text = json.dumps(received_data)
print(received_as_text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access runbook input parameters with `sys.argv`.  See [Tutorial: Create a Python 3 runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-python-3#use-input-parameters)